# Scaling in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I tested throughput performance of Cassandra cluster with 2,3 and 4 nodes. There was significant improvement when I used 3 nodes(as compared to 2), however, the improvement wasn't so significant when I used 4 nodes, instead of 3.

Given below are specs of the 4 nodes:

```
N->No. of physical CPU cores, Ra->Total RAM, Rf->Free RAM

Node 1: N=16, Ra=189 GB, Rf=165 GB
Node 2: N=16, Ra=62 GB, Rf=44 GB
Node 3: N=12, Ra=24 GB, Rf=38 GB
Node 4: N=16, Ra=189 GB, Rf=24 GB
```

All nodes are on RHEL 6.5

> **Case 1(2 nodes in the cluster, Node 1 and Node 2)**
>
> ```
> Throughput: 12K ops/second
> ```
>
> **Case 2(3 nodes in the cluster, Node 1, Node 2 and Node 3)**
>
> ```
> Throughput: 20K ops/second
> ```
>
> **Case 3(All 4 nodes in the cluster)**
>
> ```
> Throughput: 23K ops/second
> ```

1 operation involved 1 read + 1 write(Read/write takes place on the same row)(Row cache can't be used). In all cases, Read consistency =2 and Write Consistency =1. Both read and write were asynchronous. The client application used Datastax's C++ driver and was being run with 10 threads.

Given below are the keyspace and table details:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE cass WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1': '2'}  AND durable_writes = true;

CREATE TABLE cass.test_table (
    pk text PRIMARY KEY,
    data1_upd int,
    id1 int,
    portid blob,
    im text,
    isflag int,
    ms text,
    data2 int,
    rtdata blob,
    rtdynamic blob,
    rtloc blob,
    rttdd blob,
    rtaddress blob,
    status int,
    time bigint
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.001
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.LeveledCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Some parameters from YAML are given below(All 4 nodes used similar YAML files):

```
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32
concurrent_reads: 64
concurrent_writes: 256
concurrent_counter_writes: 32
memtable_offheap_space_in_mb: 20480
memtable_allocation_type: offheap_objects
memtable_flush_writers: 1
concurrent_compactors: 2
```

Some parameters from jvm.options are given below(all nodes used same values):

```
### CMS Settings
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:SurvivorRatio=4
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=6
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000
-XX:+CMSParallelInitialMarkEnabled
-XX:+CMSEdenChunksRecordAlways
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

Given below are some client's connection specific parameters:

```
cass_cluster_set_max_connections_per_host ( ms_cluster, 20 );
cass_cluster_set_queue_size_io ( ms_cluster, 102400*1024 );
cass_cluster_set_pending_requests_low_water_mark(ms_cluster, 50000);
cass_cluster_set_pending_requests_high_water_mark(ms_cluster, 100000);
cass_cluster_set_write_bytes_low_water_mark(ms_cluster, 100000 * 2024);
cass_cluster_set_write_bytes_high_water_mark(ms_cluster, 100000 * 2024);
cass_cluster_set_max_requests_per_flush(ms_cluster, 10000);
cass_cluster_set_request_timeout ( ms_cluster, 12000 );
cass_cluster_set_connect_timeout (ms_cluster, 60000);
cass_cluster_set_core_connections_per_host(ms_cluster,1);
cass_cluster_set_num_threads_io(ms_cluster,10);
cass_cluster_set_connection_heartbeat_interval(ms_cluster, 60);
cass_cluster_set_connection_idle_timeout(ms_cluster, 120);
```

Is there anything wrong with the configurations due to which Cassandra didn't scale much when number of nodes were increased from 3 to 4?

Comment: Are you sure that your application is able to saturate Cassandra? It looks also that your JVM settings not very optimal - I suggest not to tune the except `-Xmx/-Xms`, and use defaults - if you're using Java 8, then defaults are quite good

Comment: What results will be shown if you use `cassandra-stress` with your table structure?

Comment: I haven't tested cassandra-stress on the table. But apart from JVM settings, does everything else looks fine to you?

Comment: Also, what exactly did you mean by 'application being able to saturate Cassandra?'

Comment: That it sends enough queries... I would better try to test cluster with `cassandra-stress`, and see how it behaves. `cassandra-stress` is trying to increase a number of parallel requests until it reaches maximum throughput...

Comment: Those are pretty low numbers, I would agree with @AlexOtt that you are most likely rate limited on the client side. Especially if your reads and writes are done sequentially. (IE a Read depends on a write or vice versa)

Comment: But what could be the reason? Or how to debug?

Comment: I think if the throughput is really low, given the number of nodes(and their specs), then, there must be one reason behind it i.e. I must have messed up some of the parameters in the configuration, whether on the server(Cassandra yaml) or on the client(Datastax). I've just not been able to figure out what are those configurations(there's just too many of them)!

Comment: I'll try running Cassandra-stress and will share the results soon. First, I'll have to figure out how to simulate the exact same scenario in cassandra-stress i.e. read and then write(with some changes) the same row.

Answer (score 1):

During a test, you may check [ThreadPools](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsTPstats.html) using `nodetool tpstats`.
You will be able to see if some stages have too many pending (or blocked) tasks.

If there are no issues with ThreadPools, may be you cloud launch a benchmark using [cassandra-stress](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCStress.html) in order to see if the limitation comes from your client?

I don't know if it is only for test purpose but as far as I know, Read before Write data is an antipattern with Cassandra.